# $d$-regular bipartite expander graph

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, expanders

I have seen that there exists [$d$-left regular bipartite graphs](http://theory.epfl.ch/courses/topicstcs/Lecture3.pdf). My question is do there exists $d$-regular bipartite expander graphs in which *both the degree of the left and the right vertices* is exactly equal to $d$? If yes, is there any constructive proof for such graphs and what is the expansion factor? Kindly provide a reference as well.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a simple construction: Take any $d$-regular *non-bipartite* expander $G=(V,E)$ - there are several constructions of those, e.g., Margulis, or the Zig-Zag construction. Now, turn it into a bipartite graph $G' = (V_1 \cup V_2, E')$ as follows: $V_1$ and $V_2$ are copies of $V$. Two vertices $v_1 \in V_1$ and $v_2 \in V_2$ are adjacted in $G'$ if and only if the corresponding vertices in $G$ are adjacted. The expansion of $G'$ follows from the expansion of $G$.

However, one thing that should be noted is that the expansion factor in all those constructions is at most $d/2$. We do not have bipartite expanders that have a better expansion factor and are balanced (i.e. have degree $d$ on both sides).